# Ajax connection time out on firefox & Edge

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am calling a method in server side using ajax. This server side method is a batch operation and it takes around **20 - 30 mins** to complete. When I run the web site on Chrome everything works fine. Bur on Edge and Firefox the ajax `error` method is invoking after around **1 hour**. When I enable the logs the server side method is completing without an issue. But the ajax `success` method is not calling. After the server side method complete, ajax call is still active and after some time ajax error method is calling.

Furthermore, I have tried after adding a large `timeout` to the ajax call. But the result is same. Also when I runs small batch operation(around 2-3 mins). This ajax call is working on all the browsers including Firefox and Chrome.

Ajax Call configurations

```
async:true
type:POST
contentType:false
processData:false
```

Comment: So you are making a synchronous call and locking up your browser for 30-60 minutes?

Comment: @epascarello: sorry  typing mistake, ajax is async: true. Also I am showing loading wheel and status update(using separate ajax call)