# Ajax issue on Firefox when server takes long time to process

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a ajax call which calls an batch process on server side. This process will take 20-30 mins to complete. I have noticed an issue on this ajax call on Firefox and Edge browsers. 
[Ajax connection time out on firefox & Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860265/ajax-connection-time-out-on-firefox-edge)

As a solution to this, I have created a separate `ajax` call to continuously monitor the status of the batch process. If the batch process is complete this `ajax` call will show the success message. This is working fine on Chrome, Edge and Safari browsers. On Firefox when initial `ajax` call takes time to complete, the browser is initiating a second request with same data. This is causing the server to process same data twice. What can be the reason for this issue ?

Below is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({

    url : 'url',
    type : 'POST',
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    data: 'form with csv file'
    async:true,
    success : function(data) {              

    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: You are asking to debug some code that we don't see, please post your code

Comment: where it gets data for request?

Comment: on the web page there is a file upload control. This form is used as data

Comment: you have the whole code in front of you and yet having hard time to find the issue, how do you expect someone to find it without seeing the code. you should always post minimum code that's right but this minimum code must include all parts that effect the problem. you have posted a typical ajax function with no real data, we don't know what happens when ajax fails or succeeds, what function is used to get the next data for request, ....

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Actually it is a simple ajax call. The success method is showing success message and error method simply log the error and show error message. There is no ajax call inside success or error methods. And as I said in the ticket this functionally works fine on Chrome, Edge and Safari browsers.